# Why is my app not appearing on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I'm learning Rails and I am doing a Rails tutorial called Railsbridge. I have followed all the steps until the point where I deploy to Heroku (git push heroku master), but my app doesn't appear in Heroku - I just get the "We're sorry, but something went wrong" error message.

The three possible errors that come up in the terminal seem to be

1) "Gems in the groups development and test [these are in my gemfile -ed.] were not installed. It was installed into ./vendor/bundle" ( btw, there is no directory in my app's 'vendor' folder called "bundle")

2) that my app needed a procfile - but I made one!

3) this, but I don't know what it means: (process:11462): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed.

Any ideas?  I added files and committed to git before pushing, I'm sure of it.

Answer (score 2):

Run `heroku create` to create an app from the start
Make sure you are in master when using `git push heroku master`and make sure you have committed all you changes.
Then run `heroku run rake db:migrate` to migrate database to heroku. 
Sometimes you need to restart application run `heroku restart`.
You can see the error using `heroku logs`.
If you posted it on git hub, give us a link to the code.

Comment: Thanks for answer.  I've already run 'heroku create,' and it seemed to work - i.e., I have an app on Heroku, it's just not working yet.  What does it mean to be 'in master'?  I just run the 'git push' command from inside my app main folder.  Should I be somewhere else?  Lastly, how do I get the 'rake' command?  when I try to run that, I get "bash: rake:db: command not found".

Comment: Wait - I'm sorry, it looks like it might be working now!  Thanks so much!  I'll post again if I run into any more problems.  Awesome, thanks again.

Comment: My bad, its `rake db:migrate`. `git status` will tell you if you are `On branch master` or `On branch name_of_branch`. `Try.github.com`  is a good tutorial on git.