# Rails app will not work on Heroku after deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, heroku

I have been attempting to deploy a Rails 4/AngularJS (Ruby 2.2.3/Rails 4.2.4) app to Heroku based on this tutorial (http://angular-rails.com/bootstrap.html). It simply had me create Rails 4 app with a PostgreSQL db and serve the AngularJS and Bootstrap using the "bower-rails" gem. The app is very simple at this point and works perfectly fine locally. At first, I thought it was a Windows issue, since I had originally started building the app on my Windows 10 machine, but I have replicated everything from scratch on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine with the same results.

I believe there is an issue with the file paths, which according to the Heroku tutorial (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline) I saw should have been fixed with the "rails_12factor" gem and/or by adding "config.serve_static_assets = true" to config/application.rb, both of which I did. I pushed my Gemfile, Gemfile.lock, Procfile, config/application.rb and Rakefile to Heroku and nothing has made my app work.

After trying everything I could, I built a new empty Rails app with a PG db, to rule out the AngularJS/Bootstrap assets causing the error and the result was the same. Here is the bottom part of the logs from that deployment:

```
remote:        Bundle complete! 17 Gemfile dependencies, 54 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Post-install message from rdoc:
remote:        Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:
remote:        <= 1.8.6 : unsupported
remote:        = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
remote:        = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
remote:        >= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
remote:        Bundle completed (29.50s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: 
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> web
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> console, rake, worker
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 31.3M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v5
remote:        https://desolate-river-80004.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy.... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/desolate-river-80004.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

---

After deploying, this message came after I entered "heroku open":

```
Opening desolate-river-80004... done

(process:14649): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
```

---

I have tried pretty much everything I can. Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.2.3"


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
# gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'sass', '3.2.19'

gem "bower-rails"
gem "puma"

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.0"
  gem "factory_girl_rails", "~> 4.0"
  gem "capybara"
  gem "database_cleaner"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
end

gem "foreman"
group :production, :staging do
  gem "rails_12factor"
  gem "rails_stdout_logging"
  gem "rails_serve_static_assets"
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Comment: Is this helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27411043/why-is-my-app-not-appearing-on-heroku

Comment: Did you do your database creation, migrations and seeding, assets precompilation for heroku, pushing the master branch to heroku etc ?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I think that the ultimate problem had to do with not committing everything into the git repo. I started over from scratch by following the Heroku tutorial on deplying Rails 4x to Heroku (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4) and deployed an empty app, which worked. Then I used a hybrid of those instructions and the Angular-Rails tutorial to rebuild the app and deploy it successfully. Long story short, that tutorial is pretty incomplete and I had to take note of all the inaccurate/incomplete info in it.